# I am getting the error Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I have looked at all the previous replies to this type of question and did not see any that seemed to fit.  The line that gives me the error is:

```
"÷" : .binaryOperation(/,{$0 + "÷" + $1}, {$1 == 0 ? "Division by zero" : nil}),
```

When I change it to this it code compiles with no errors:

```
"÷" : .binaryOperation(/,{$0 + "÷" + $1}, {_,_ nil}),
```

The complete expression i:

```
    private var operations:Dictionary<String,Operation> =
        [
            "rand": .nullOperation({Double(arc4random()) / Double(UInt32.max)}, "rand()"),
            "π" : .constant(M_PI),
            "e" : .constant(M_E),
            "√" : .unaryOperation(sqrt,{"√(" + $0 + ")"},{$0 < 0 ? "Sqrt of negative number" : nil}),
            "cos" :.unaryOperation(cos,{"cos(" + $0 + ")"},{ _ in nil}),
            "∓" : .unaryOperation({-$0},{"-(" + $0 + ")"},{ _ in nil}),
            "x²" :.unaryOperation({ pow($0, 2) }, { "(" + $0 + ")²" },{ _ in nil}),
            "x³" :.unaryOperation({ pow($0, 3) }, { "(" + $0 + ")³" },{ _ in nil}),
            "x⁻¹" :.unaryOperation({ 1 / $0 }, {  "(" + $0 + ")⁻¹" },{ _ in nil}),
            "sin" :.unaryOperation(sin, { "sin(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "tan" :.unaryOperation(tan, { "tan(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "sinh" :.unaryOperation(sinh, { "sinh(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "cosh" :.unaryOperation(cosh, { "cosh(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "tanh" :.unaryOperation(tanh, { "tanh(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "ln" :  .unaryOperation(log, { "ln(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "log" : .unaryOperation(log10, { "log(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "eˣ" :.unaryOperation(exp, { "e^(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "10ˣ" :.unaryOperation({ pow(10, $0) }, { "10^(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil}),
            "x!" :.unaryOperation(factorial, { "(" + $0 + ")!" },{ _ in nil}),
            "xʸ" :.binaryOperation(pow, { $0 + "^" + $1 },{ _,_ in nil}),
            "+" : .binaryOperation(+,{$0 + "+" + $1},{ _,_ in nil}),
            "−" : .binaryOperation(-,{$0 + "-" + $1},{ _,_ in nil}),
            "÷" : .binaryOperation(/,{$0 + "÷" + $1}, {$1 == 0 ? "Division by zero" : nil}),
            "×" : .binaryOperation(*,{$0 + "*" + $1},{ _,_ in nil}),
            "=" : .equals
    ]
```

---

Edit: Here is the Operation enum

```
private enum Operation { 
    case constant(Double) 
    case nullOperation(() -> Double, String) 
    case unaryOperation((Double) -> Double, (String) -> String, (Double) -> String?) 
    case binaryOperation((Double,Double) -> Double, (String, String) -> String, (Double,Double) -> String?)
    case equals 
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `Operation` enum to the question so we can recreate this in a playground please?

Comment: maybe related: https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/07/12/type-checker-issues.html

Comment: private enum Operation {
            case constant(Double)
            case nullOperation(() -> Double, String)
            case unaryOperation((Double) -> Double, (String) -> String, (Double) -> String?)
            case binaryOperation((Double,Double) -> Double, (String, String) -> String, (Double,Double) -> String?)
            case equals
        }

Comment: @TomAravanis, precisions to a question need to be included in the question itself with an edit, not added as a comment. And read the article I gave, you fall precisely into the issue described, so you get great explanations and workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Testing this in a playground shows that **this doesn't help**. I'm leaving it here so other people know not to try it ;)

<guess>

Can you try being explicit about the arguments to your final block i.e. something like

```
"÷" : .binaryOperation(/,{$0 + "÷" + $1}, { (_, denom: Double) -> String? in 
    return denom == 0 ? "Division by zero" : nil
}),
```

</guess>

Comment: @Cœur that's much more likely, yes :) I've asked the op to add the `Operation` enum to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding each line to the dictionary individually works, but it's not fast :)

```
private var operations: [String: Operation] = [:]

operations["rand"] = .nullOperation({Double(arc4random()) / Double(UInt32.max)}, "rand()")
operations["π"] = .constant(.pi)
operations["e"] = .constant(M_E)
operations["√"] = .unaryOperation(sqrt,{"√(" + $0 + ")"},{$0 < 0 ? "Sqrt of negative number" : nil})
operations["cos"] = .unaryOperation(cos,{"cos(" + $0 + ")"},{ _ in nil})
operations["∓"] = .unaryOperation({-$0},{"-(" + $0 + ")"},{ _ in nil})
operations["x²"] = .unaryOperation({ pow($0, 2) }, { "(" + $0 + ")²" },{ _ in nil})
operations["x³"] = .unaryOperation({ pow($0, 3) }, { "(" + $0 + ")³" },{ _ in nil})
operations["x⁻¹"] = .unaryOperation({ 1 / $0 }, {  "(" + $0 + ")⁻¹" },{ _ in nil})
operations["sin"] = .unaryOperation(sin, { "sin(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil})
operations["tan"] = .unaryOperation(tan, { "tan(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil})
operations["sinh"] = .unaryOperation(sinh, { "sinh(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil})
operations["cosh"] = .unaryOperation(cosh, { "cosh(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil})
operations["tanh"] = .unaryOperation(tanh, { "tanh(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil})
operations["ln"] = .unaryOperation(log, { "ln(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil})
operations["log"] = .unaryOperation(log10, { "log(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil})
operations["eˣ"] = .unaryOperation(exp, { "e^(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil})
operations["10ˣ"] = .unaryOperation({ pow(10, $0) }, { "10^(" + $0 + ")" },{ _ in nil})
operations["x!"] = .unaryOperation(factorial, { "(" + $0 + ")!" },{ _ in nil})
operations["xʸ"] = .binaryOperation(pow, { $0 + "^" + $1 },{ _,_ in nil})
operations["+"] = .binaryOperation(+,{$0 + "+" + $1},{ _,_ in nil})
operations["−"] = .binaryOperation(-,{$0 + "-" + $1},{ _,_ in nil})
operations["÷"] = .binaryOperation(/,{$0 + "÷" + $1}, { $1 == Double(0) ? "Division by zero" : nil})
operations["×"] = .binaryOperation(*,{$0 + "*" + $1},{ _,_ in nil})
operations["="] = .equals
```